# Scrollbar of a webbrowser control doesn't work correctly if enclosed in a tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a program that has use of a webbrowser control.  When enclosed in the main grid something like this:

```
<grid>
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" .../>
</grid>
```

The scrollbars work like they should, it goes to the extremes of the page.

however in if i want to put the webbrowser control in a tabcontrol, say because i wanted a tabbed browser, with the code like this

```
<grid>
<tabcontrol ...>
<tabitem ... >
<grid....>
<webBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1"  />
</grid>
</tabitem>
</grid>
```

The scrollbars of the webbrowser control are not scrolling to the ends of the page, instead it it stops about 10% from the end horizontally and vertically.

Is there a way to get s tabbed browsercontrol that doesn't truncate the page?

Here is the more detailed code

```
<tabcontrol Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,272,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width=1000>
<Tabitem Header="FlexWebApp" Name="FWA" scrollViewer.VerticalSchollBarVisibility="Auto">
<grid Schrollviewer.VerticalScrollbarvisibility="hidden" name="FWAGrid>
<WebBrowser Name="WFWA" Source="pathToApplication"/>
</Grid>
</TabItem>
<TabItem header= AnalyseFWA Name="AFWA ...>

<Tabitem Header="SLWebApp" Name="SLA" scrollViewer.VerticalSchollBarVisibility="Auto">
<grid Schrollviewer.VerticalScrollbarvisibility="hidden" name="SLAGrid>
<WebBrowser Name="WSLA" Source="pathToApplication"/>
<TabItem header= AnalyseSLA Name="ASLA ...>
</Grid>
</TabItem>
```

So if it's not apparent the webbrowsers are directed to one silverlight app and one flex app both apps get truncated.  In fact on both cases, the grid that encloses the apps' scrollbar is always visible despite the hidden attribute.

The truncation does not occur on regular browsers.
Could it be that the apps are misreporting its size?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your XAML?

I couldn't duplicate your issue. I created a new WPF Application project in Visual Studio 2010 and changed only the XAML and I did not have this issue.

```
<Window x:Class="TestBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Rhyous.com">
                <Grid>
                    <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser" Source="http://www.rhyous.com"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The entire web page was displayed.

So my guess is that you will see the same if you create a sample project. Then you can start adding what you did in your real project to your sample until you find what is really breaking it.

Comment: You are right about the browser not truncating the page on a sample app... i've posted as much as i'm allowed to.